# pyqt dropEvent will not fire

Tags: python, qt, events, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I am trying to drag a list item onto another list. The dragEnterEvent fires just fine, I do e.accept(), however the dropEvent never fires. Here's the code:

```
class LocalList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LocalList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText(self.currentItem().text())
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        dropAction = drag.exec_()

class RemoteList(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(RemoteList, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print "MimeText: " + e.mimeData().text()
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print "DROPPED"
        print self.parent.localdir + "/" + e.mimeData().text()
        e.accept()
```

To clarify, I'm dragging from LocalList to RemoteList. The mousMoveEvent is being fired just fine, because the mimeData().text() prints out just fine in RemoteList's dragEnterEvent. I don't think it's accepting right though, because dropEvent is never fired, and when I'm hovering over the RemoteList it doesn't have the "drop here" icon.

Comment: I think you have to implement both `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543644/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-qlistwidget-to-another) for another similar question

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot :)

I don't seem able to accept your answer in this form.

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was all that was required, but it that solved it you can accept my answer below now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement both `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543644/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-qlistwidget-to-another) for another similar question

This seems to do what you need rather short and elegant :)

```
class DragDropListWidget(QtGui.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, type, parent=None):
        super(DragDropListWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```