# QGraphicsView Drag&Drop not working when dragging local image to my app

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

**What is happening is the following issue:**

1. I have my own overwritten [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html).
2. I superscribe my tho methods, [dragEnterEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) and [dropEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html).
3. When I drag an image from the browser, for example from chrome, both are executed. (PERFECT)
4. BUT when I drag an image from a local folder, from my local explorer to inside my application, only the **dragEnterEvent** is executed but not my **dropEvent**
5. My approach is that inside my **dragEnterEvent** I work on the [QPixMap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html) creation and local save and inside my **dropEvent** I would add this image into my **QGraphicsScene**
6. **I would like to know how to make the dropEvent catch the event and be executed when a local image is dropped inside my scene.**

***Here is what I have so far:***

**My dragEnterEvent:**

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event):
    q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.acceptProposedAction()
    try:
        if q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            print('LOCAL / CHROME')
            url = str(q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().urls()[0].url())
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            image = QImage()
            image.loadFromData(data)
            self.browser_img = QPixmap(image)
            self.browser_img.save("resources/my_image.png")
            print("LOCAL / CHROME finalized")
        else:
            print("WEBVIEW")
            html = q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().html()
            matches = re.search('src="([^"]+)"', html)
            url = matches.group()[5:-1]
            print(url)
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
            image = QImage()
            image.loadFromData(data)
            self.browser_img = QPixmap(image)
            self.browser_img.save("resources/my_image.png")
            print("WEBVIEW finalized")
    except:

        print('error',sys.exc_info())
        self.update()

    # HERE I CAN USE THE CODE OF THE DROPEVENT, BUT EACH TIME THAT I
    # GET OUT AND GET INSIDE MY SCENE THE IMAGE WILL BE ADDED AGAIN.
    # I DON'T WANT THAT.
    # self.graphics_image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.browser_img)
    # self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
    # self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    # self.addItem(self.graphics_image)
    # self.graphics_image.setPos(q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.scenePos())
```

**My dropEvent:**

```
def dropEvent(self, event):
    # HERE IS THE WORKING CODE BUT ONLY EXECUTED WHEN IMAGE DRAGGED FROM
    # BROWSER, NOT EXECUTED WHEN FROM A LOCAL FOLDER.
    self.graphics_image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.browser_img)
    self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
    self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    self.addItem(self.graphics_image)
    # QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent.screenPos()
    self.graphics_image.setPos(event.scenePos())
    super(InteractQGraphicsScene, self).dropEvent(event)
```

**And in my view I also setted that drop is accepted, using:**

```
self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

**ALLL THE CODE WORKS PERFECTLY, URL REQUISITION, IMAGE CREATION, IMAGE ADDING.
AGAIN, THE ONLY PROBLEM IS THE dragEvent NOT BEING EXECUTED WHEN FROM LOCAL FOLDER.**

Comment: did you try implementing the `dragMoveEvent` also ? A nice example can be found here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543644/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-qlistwidget-to-another)

Comment: kinda did, worked fine after many tries :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer to my problem.

1. I made a small example to see what was the problem.
2. Just implementing the dragEnterEvent, dropEvent on the view and accepting drop events would work fine.(***IF I HAD ONLY THE VIEW AND DEFAULT SCENE***)
3. Since I have my own personalized Scene I had to do the following thing:
4. To re-implement the dragEnterEvent and the dragMoveEvent, and accept their event in the scene.
5. And implement my final logic on the view.
6. Now all work perfectly :D

**"Flag" on the view:**

```
self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

**VIEW :**

```
 def dragEnterEvent(self, q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event):

    q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.accept()
    q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.acceptProposedAction()
    try:
        if q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            print("local chrome")
            url = str(q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().urls()[0].url())
            NAM_CREATOR.get_nam().request_image(url)
        else:
            print("webview")
            html = q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event.mimeData().html()
            matches = re.search('src="([^"]+)"', html)
            url = matches.group()[5:-1]
            NAM_CREATOR.get_nam().request_image(url)
    except RuntimeError:
        print('error',sys.exc_info())
        pass
    super(ScreenViewScene, self).dragEnterEvent(
        q_graphics_scene_drag_drop_event)

def dragMoveEvent(self, QDragMoveEvent):
    QDragMoveEvent.accept()
    super(ScreenViewScene, self).dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent)

def dropEvent(self, event):
    print("LEAVE")
    image = QPixmap("resources/browser_images/image_required_browser")
    self.graphics_image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(image)
    self.graphics_image.acceptDrops()
    self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
    self.graphics_image.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    self.scene.addItem(self.graphics_image)
    self.graphics_image.setPos(event.pos())
    NAM_CREATOR.get_nam().deleteLater()
    NAM_CREATOR.reset_nam()

    super(ScreenViewScene, self).dropEvent(event)
```

**Scene:**

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent):
    QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent.accept()

def dragMoveEvent(self, QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent):
    QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent.accept()
```