# PyQt - Add drag & drop to widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a class that inherits from QWidget :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, layoutname: str, width: int, height: int ) -> None:
        """
        Constructor, pass 0 to width and/or height if you want them to be defaults given at runtime
        :param layoutname: Layout, a Layout object will be built according to the class name passed
        :param width: int,  width of the widget
        :param height: int, height of the widget
        """
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

    if width != 0:
        self.setFixedWidth(width)

    if height != 0:
        self.setFixedHeight(height)

    layout = layoutname()
    self.setLayout(layout)


def addChild(self, child: object)-> None:
    """
    Adds child as a child to the widget
    :param child: Widget, the child you want to add to the current widget
    """
    self.layout().addWidget(child)

def droppedR(self):
    print("DROPPED")
```

I want to add the following feature: When something is dropped (let's say a file) on the widget, I want to call droppedR(). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it answers you exactly what you want, but I had some problems before with dragDrop and maybe this question and answer that I spent a really long time can help you out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806320/qgraphicsview-dragdrop-not-working-when-dragging-local-image-to-my-app).

Summarizing, the main reasoning would be:

1. Accept dragDrop events with `accept()` and `acceptProposedAction()` methods
2. Re-implement the `dragEnterEvent` `dragMoveEvent` and `dropEvent`.
3. Inside these methods you should do what you want. For example call your droppedR methods inside the `dropEvent` methods.

It's up to you the logic you want to apply in each of the events.