# PyQt, moving an item from a QListWidget to the other QListWidget using drag and drop

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to move an item in a QListWidget (list A) to the other QListWidget (list B) using drag and drop. I can copy the item to list B, but I cannot remove the item in list A. I tried to use 'dragLeaveEvent' function, but the event has no QMimeData, so I cannot access to the item leaving list A. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I also am working on this problem. I looked at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543644/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-qlistwidget-to-another

However, the code on that page only places a copy of the dragged item in the new list. The item still remains in the old list.